# LINQ to SQL group by shows wrong count of distinct foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Table and the required data are in the following SQL Code, use this SQL code to see my required report output. I want to achieve this same report in C# LINQ.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tbl_GrandParent') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE Tbl_GrandParent;
END
GO
CREATE TABLE Tbl_GrandParent (
  GPID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  GP_Name nvarchar(75),
  GP_Wealth float
);
GO

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_GrandParent] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_GrandParent] ([GPID], [GP_Name], [GP_Wealth])
  VALUES (1, N'GP_A TO D', 100)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_GrandParent] ([GPID], [GP_Name], [GP_Wealth])
  VALUES (2, N'GP_E TO H', 100)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_GrandParent] ([GPID], [GP_Name], [GP_Wealth])
  VALUES (3, N'GP_I TO L', 100)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_GrandParent] OFF
GO

GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Tbl_Parent') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE Tbl_Parent;
END
GO
CREATE TABLE Tbl_Parent (
  PID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  GPID int REFERENCES Tbl_GrandParent (GPID) NOT NULL,
  P_Name nvarchar(75),
  P_Wealth float
);
GO

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Parent] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Parent] ([PID], [GPID], [P_Name], [P_Wealth])
  VALUES (1, 1, N'P_B', 50)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Parent] ([PID], [GPID], [P_Name], [P_Wealth])
  VALUES (2, 1, N'P_c', 50)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Parent] ([PID], [GPID], [P_Name], [P_Wealth])
  VALUES (3, 2, N'P_E', 50)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Parent] OFF
GO

GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Tbl_Child') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE Tbl_Child;
END
GO
CREATE TABLE Tbl_Child (
  CID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  PID int REFERENCES Tbl_Parent (PID) NOT NULL,
  C_Name nvarchar(75),
  C_Wealth float
);
GO

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Child] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Child] ([CID], [PID], [C_Name], [C_Wealth])
  VALUES (1, 1, N'C_P_1.1', 25)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Child] ([CID], [PID], [C_Name], [C_Wealth])
  VALUES (2, 1, N'C_P_1.2', 25)
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Child] ([CID], [PID], [C_Name], [C_Wealth])
  VALUES (3, 2, N'C_P_2.1', 25)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Child] OFF
GO

GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Tbl_WealthSpent') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE Tbl_WealthSpent;
END
GO
CREATE TABLE Tbl_WealthSpent (
  WSID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  CID int REFERENCES Tbl_Child (CID) NOT NULL,
  FromTime datetime NOT NULL,
  ToTime datetime NOT NULL
);
GO

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_WealthSpent] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_WealthSpent] ([WSID], [CID], [FromTime], [ToTime])
  VALUES (1, 1, CAST(0x0000A7D4009450C0 AS datetime), CAST(0x0000A7D400A4CB80 AS datetime))
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_WealthSpent] ([WSID], [CID], [FromTime], [ToTime])
  VALUES (3, 1, CAST(0x0000A7D400A4CB80 AS datetime), CAST(0x0000A7D400B54640 AS datetime))
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_WealthSpent] ([WSID], [CID], [FromTime], [ToTime])
  VALUES (4, 1, CAST(0x0000A7D400B54640 AS datetime), CAST(0x0000A7D400C5C100 AS datetime))
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_WealthSpent] ([WSID], [CID], [FromTime], [ToTime])
  VALUES (5, 3, CAST(0x0000A7D4009450C0 AS datetime), CAST(0x0000A7D400A4CB80 AS datetime))
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_WealthSpent] ([WSID], [CID], [FromTime], [ToTime])
  VALUES (7, 3, CAST(0x0000A7D400A4CB80 AS datetime), CAST(0x0000A7D400B54640 AS datetime))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_WealthSpent] OFF
GO


GO

SELECT
  gp.GPID,
  gp.GP_Name,
  gp.GP_Wealth,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (p.PID)) ChildCount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (c.CID)) GrandChildCount,
  CAST((SUM(DATEDIFF(SS, WS.FromTime, WS.ToTime)) / 3600) AS decimal(10, 2)) WealthSpent
FROM Tbl_GrandParent AS gp
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Parent AS p
  ON p.GPID = gp.GPID
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Child AS c
  ON c.PID = p.PID
LEFT JOIN Tbl_WealthSpent AS ws
  ON ws.CID = c.CID
GROUP BY gp.GPID,
         gp.GP_Name,
         gp.GP_Wealth
```

Screenshot of MS SQL Join Query result:

[image]

I want to achieve this result in C# LINQ,

My actual C# LINQ code and its data result:

```
 var details = (from gp in dc.Tbl_GrandParents
                join p in dc.Tbl_Parents on gp.GPID equals p.GPID into p_join
                from p in p_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join c in dc.Tbl_Childs on p.PID equals c.PID into c_join
                from c in c_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join ws in dc.Tbl_WealthSpents on c.CID equals ws.CID into ws_join
                from ws in ws_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                group new { gp, p, c, ws } by new
                 {
                    GPID = gp.GPID,
                    GPName = gp.GP_Name,
                    GPWealth = gp.GP_Wealth
                 } into g
                select new 
                {
                    GPID = g.Key.GPID,
                    GPName = g.Key.GPName,
                    GPWealth = g.Key.GPWealth,
                    ChildCount = g.Select(s=>s.p.PID != null).Distinct().Count(),
                    GrandChildCount = g.Select(s => s.c.CID != null).Distinct().Count(),
                    WealthSpent = ((g.Select(t => (t.ws.ToTime - t.ws.FromTime).TotalSeconds).Sum() / 3600) != null) ? ((decimal)g.Select(t => (t.ws.ToTime - t.ws.FromTime).TotalSeconds).Sum() / 3600) : (decimal)0.0,
                }).ToList();
```

LINQ achieved data report screenshot:

[image]

Expected Data:

```
GPID | GP_Name | GP_Wealth | ChildCount | GrandChildCount | WealthSpent
-----|---------|-----------|------------|-----------------|-----------
1    |GP_A TO D|100        |2           |3                |5.00
2    |GP_E TO H|100        |1           |0                |NULL
3    |GP_I TO L|100        |0           |0                |NULL
```

Actual Data:

```
GPID | GP_Name | GP_Wealth | ChildCount | GrandChildCount | WealthSpent
-----|---------|-----------|------------|-----------------|-----------
1    |GP_A TO D|100        |1           |1                |5.00
2    |GP_E TO H|100        |1           |1                |0.00
3    |GP_I TO L|100        |1           |1                |0.00
```

Here ChildCount and GrandChildCount value obtained is wrong when compared to SQL Join output.

Comment: Please include in the text of your question some sample data, the **expected** output you should receive for that sample data and the **actual** output for that sample data.

Comment: expected output is shown in the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnWgy.png             Acutal output achieved using LINQ  https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Szv.png    Is that ok @mjwills..?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] - if you can reproduce it with linq to objects, that would be ideal.

Comment: you dont need to check `s.p.PID != null` because you already selecting as `join p in dc.Tbl_Parents on gp.GPID equals p.GPID into p_join`

Comment: Use navigation properties, no joins. If this is LINQ-to-SQL (please always mention the type of LINQ!) they should be readily available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your current code is not doing what you think it is doing.

What you *likely* think it is doing is counting the number of distinct PID (or SID). But what it is **actually** doing is counting the number of distinct results of `s.p.PID != null`.

Now, the result of that `s.p.PID != null` calculation is a bool (i.e. true / 
 false) - and due to the nature of your data and query, it will *always* return `true`. So, you have a set of data all containing `true`. You run `Distinct` on it, and get a single `true`. Then you `Count` that single `true` and you get 1.

To fix this, you likely need to change:

```
ChildCount = g.Select(s=>s.p.PID != null).Distinct().Count(),
GrandChildCount = g.Select(s => s.c.CID != null).Distinct().Count(),
```

to something like:

```
ChildCount = g.Select(s=>s.p.PID).Where(z => z != null).Distinct().Count(),
GrandChildCount = g.Select(s => s.c.CID).Where(z => z != null).Distinct().Count(),
```

*The `.Where(z => z != null)` bit is optional - you could remove it if you like. I have included it there only to try and replicate what you were likely trying to do with your original code (i.e. exclude null PIDs and SIDs).*

Comment: @ Your solution worked with including.Where(z => z != null), but I couldn't realise what is happening in it.  what is the difference between my code   .Select(s=>s.p.PID != null)  and yours  .Select(s=>s.p.PID).Where(z => z != null).

Comment: Read the first three paragraphs of my answer. Did that make sense?

Comment: Now i have seen explanation. I can understand difference in specifying the Where condition after Select condition. marked your solution as answer.

Comment: The **order** is not the important thing. The key is that `.Select(s=>s.p.PID != null` doesn't mean 'return me the PIDs which aren't null'. It means 'return me false or true, depending on whether the PID is null or not null` (which is not what you want).

Answer (score 0):

I am very surprised that your current code was working at all.  I would have expected a null reference exception because you are doing successive left joins on ids that potentially do not exist.

I also find with Linq that it often helps to break the operation down into two or more subsidiary steps.  It helps me at any rate to work out what is going on even if it doesn't help the compiler.  This is particularly true where there are various sub-levels of joins.

Please note for test purposes I simply put the values direct into a List, but it will be easy for you to change this.

```
private class tbl_GrandParent
{
    public int GPID { get; set; }
    public string GP_Name { get; set; }
    public double GP_Wealth { get; set; }
}
private class tbl_Parent
{
    public int PID { get; set; }
    public int GPID { get; set; }
    public string P_Name { get; set; }
    public double P_Wealth { get; set; }
}
private class tbl_Child
{
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public int PID { get; set; }
    public string C_Name { get; set; }
    public double C_Wealth { get; set; }
}
private class tbl_WealthSpent
{
    public int WSID { get; set; }
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToTime { get; set; }
}
private void Test()
{

    try
    {
        List<tbl_GrandParent> gps = new List<tbl_GrandParent>();
        gps.Add(new tbl_GrandParent { GPID = 1, GP_Name = "GP_A TO D", GP_Wealth = 100 });
        gps.Add(new tbl_GrandParent { GPID = 2, GP_Name = "GP_E TO H", GP_Wealth = 100 });
        gps.Add(new tbl_GrandParent { GPID = 3, GP_Name = "GP_I TO L", GP_Wealth = 100 });
        List<tbl_Parent> ps = new List<tbl_Parent>();
        ps.Add(new tbl_Parent { PID = 1, GPID = 1, P_Name = "P_B", P_Wealth = 50 });
        ps.Add(new tbl_Parent { PID = 2, GPID = 1, P_Name = "P_c", P_Wealth = 50 });
        ps.Add(new tbl_Parent { PID = 3, GPID = 2, P_Name = "P_E", P_Wealth = 50 });
        List<tbl_Child> cs = new List<tbl_Child>();
        cs.Add(new tbl_Child { CID = 1, PID = 1, C_Name = "C_P_1.1", C_Wealth = 25 });
        cs.Add(new tbl_Child { CID = 2, PID = 1, C_Name = "C_P_1.2", C_Wealth = 25 });
        cs.Add(new tbl_Child { CID = 3, PID = 2, C_Name = "C_P_2.1", C_Wealth = 25 });
        List<tbl_WealthSpent> wss = new List<tbl_WealthSpent>();
        wss.Add(new tbl_WealthSpent { WSID = 1, CID = 1, FromTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 9, 0, 0), ToTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 10, 0, 0) });
        wss.Add(new tbl_WealthSpent { WSID = 3, CID = 1, FromTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 10, 0, 0), ToTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 11, 0, 0) });
        wss.Add(new tbl_WealthSpent { WSID = 4, CID = 1, FromTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 11, 0, 0), ToTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 12, 0, 0) });
        wss.Add(new tbl_WealthSpent { WSID = 5, CID = 3, FromTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 9, 0, 0), ToTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 10, 0, 0) });
        wss.Add(new tbl_WealthSpent { WSID = 7, CID = 3, FromTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 10, 0, 0), ToTime = new DateTime(2017, 8, 19, 11, 0, 0) });

        var details = from gp in gps
                        join p in ps on gp.GPID equals p.GPID into p_join
                        from p in p_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join c in cs on p?.PID ?? 0 equals c.PID into c_join
                        from c in c_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join ws in wss on c?.CID ?? 0 equals ws.CID into ws_join
                        from ws in ws_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            GPID = gp.GPID,
                            GP_Name = gp.GP_Name,
                            GP_Wealth = gp.GP_Wealth,
                            PID = p?.PID ?? null,
                            CID = c?.CID ?? null,
                            FromTime = ws?.FromTime ?? null,
                            ToTime = ws?.ToTime ?? null
                        };

        var grp = details.GroupBy(x => new { x.GPID, x.GP_Name, x.GP_Wealth })
                            .Select(g => new
                            {
                                GPID = g.Key.GPID,
                                GP_Name = g.Key.GP_Name,
                                GP_Wealth = g.Key.GP_Wealth,
                                ChildCount = g.Where(x => x.PID != null).Select(x => x.PID).Distinct().Count(),
                                GrandChildCount = g.Where(x => x.CID != null).Select(x => x.CID).Distinct().Count(),
                                WealthSpent = g.Where(x => x.FromTime != null).Sum(t => ((TimeSpan)(t.ToTime - t.FromTime)).TotalSeconds / 3600)
                            });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception thrown; " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Expanding Results View on grp in Debugger gives

```
-       Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable   
+       [0] { GPID = 1, GP_Name = "GP_A TO D", GP_Wealth = 100, ChildCount = 2, GrandChildCount = 3, WealthSpent = 5 }  <Anonymous Type>
+       [1] { GPID = 2, GP_Name = "GP_E TO H", GP_Wealth = 100, ChildCount = 1, GrandChildCount = 0, WealthSpent = 0 }  <Anonymous Type>
+       [2] { GPID = 3, GP_Name = "GP_I TO L", GP_Wealth = 100, ChildCount = 0, GrandChildCount = 0, WealthSpent = 0 }  <Anonymous Type>
```

Comment: tried your code, i am getting error notification in this line "cs on p?.PID ?? 0". @mjwills Solution of working for me, even your solution is also same.

Comment: I feel code execution time increases in your case when you separate the join query, what is your opinion regarding this?.  Can you explain this code "p?.PID ?? null,"    because i never came accross of such code if condition style

Comment: @PraneshJanarthanan I believe this syntax came in with c# 6.0. It is a short form check that you are joining to a value rather than null (which is possible because p is itself a left join).  Which version of c# are you using?

Comment: @PraneshJanarthanan as to code execution time increasing, you would need to run tests.  In SQL Server itself, I have sometimes found the opposite to be true.  Sometimes breaking down an operation helps the compiler, because the human brain can see the best execution path, which the optimiser might not find by itself.

Comment: It is not C# 6.0.   `into c_join from c in c_join.DefaultIfEmpty()` will manage your point **I would have expected a null reference exception because you are doing successive left joins on ids that potentially do not exist**. I am not theoratically strong, but practically i knew it.